# Can I register as an individual if I have joined another organization in AppStoreConnect

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, apple-developer

I want to publish my apps, but not under the brand name of the organization I am a member of. Can I have an individual program if I am already a member of the organization in AppStoreConnect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but you need to sign up for a new Apple ID, and then enroll that Apple ID in your individual program. You can do so here: http://appleid.apple.com